# Convert (comma separated hex) String to unsigned char array in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, nodemcu, string-conversion

The response payload of my http request looks like this (but can be modified to any string best suitable for the task):

```
"{0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00,
0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,}"
```

How do I turn it into an unsigned char array containing the hex values like this:

```
unsigned char gImage_test[14] = { 0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00,
0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,}
```

Additional information: The length of the payload string is known in advance and always the same. Some partial solution I found can't be directly applied due to the limitations of the wrapper nature of Arduino for c++. Looking for a simple solution within the Arduino IDE.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work, or not work? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does ardunio support the stream library?

Comment: If you have a programming question, why you have "Arduino IDE" in your head line. Your question is C++ and not for the IDE! You may tell us that you run on avr 8 bit, because of low resources available. But the rest is useless here...

Comment: @Klaus I dont know the proper name, but it is some C++ dialect on arduino, not really C++, though "IDE" is really misplaced...

Comment: no! it is not a dialect, it is simply c++ but not all library stuff is available. So it is worth to tell it is avr but the question is not related to the IDE at all. So please remove this. Other users which have questions for the IDE may find this question without any help.

Comment: @Klaus Removed IDE from the title. Thanks.

Comment: We need sehe to come in with some Boost.Spirit monstrosity :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `sscanf("%x", ...)`, here an example of just 3 hex numbers:

```
const char *buffer = "{0X00,0X01,0XC8}";
unsigned int data[3];
int read_count = sscanf(buffer, "{%x,%x,%x}", data, data+1, data+2);
// if successful read_count will be 3
```

Comment: That `char*` initialisation is invalid in C++. Make it `const` and you're ok though

Comment: It's a little problematic if the size of the input is long, and even worse if it's unknown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude agreed but this fits the OP's constraints (the size of the input is known and, assuming we take the example literally, small enough)

Comment: and also the format string can be constructed during runtime... a bit of transfer power is requested here ;)

Comment: ok so something like `while(sscanf(buffer + offset, "%x", &array[inx]) == 1) offset += 5;` is another alternative

Answer (score 0):

If using [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (`#include <stdio.h>`) is within your limitations then you can call with it `"%hhx"` to extract each individual hex value into an `unsigned char` like this:

```
const int PAYLOAD_LENGTH = 14; // Known in advance
unsigned char gImage_test[PAYLOAD_LENGTH];

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* bufferPtr = "{0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF}";
    for (int i = 0; i < PAYLOAD_LENGTH && sscanf(bufferPtr + 1, "%hhx", &gImage_test[i]); i++, bufferPtr += 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Julian I just saw you update to the question and accordingly edited the answer.